# "I hope this could help you" vs. "I hope it can help you" vs. "Hoped this may help you"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Which of the following is grammatical when giving someone something they want?

> - I hope this could help you.
> - I hope it can help you.
> - Hoped this may help you.

Comment: "Jill, here's a lockpick. It might be handy if you, the master of unlocking, take it with you."

Answer (score 12):

"I hope this could help you" sounds wrong. As *could* is past tense, and you're taking about present/future tense.

"I hope this can help you" is okay, but not very strong as you are only hoping the thing has the *capability* to help.

"I hope this may help you" is also okay, and is a bit stronger, as you are hoping that the thing has a *likelihood*, or a *probability* of helping.

I would also consider, "I hope this will help you", as this is the strongest, and hopes that the thing will most *definitely*, *certainly* help.

Comment: Why not simply *I hope this helps you* ?

Comment: Because it is decaf.

Answer (score -1):

Could can also be used as an alternative to can suggesting less force or certainty or as a polite form in the present

"I hope this could help..."  note sure if it helps.

according to merriam dictionary :-)